# The word 'like' before a verb and after a noun

Tags: prepositions, comparative-constructions

I'm reading a book by Salman Rushdie (Shame) and came to such a sentence, where I'm not sure to which word the phrase with *like* refers.

> ...while that wind like the cough of a sick giant burned away her eyebrows (which never grew again)

Does it mean

- The wind was like the cough of a sick giant, OR
- The wind burned away her eyebrows in the same way as the cough of sick giant would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that both your options are very similar in meaning. But in essence, the writer compared the force/strength of the wind to the cough of a sick giant. Such a thing would have burned away her eyebrows in the same way the wind did.